# Custom Header not being added at final HTTP response - APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse class from AWS .NET Lambda SDK

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-net

### Description

I'm working with AWS Lambda BUT without the `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer` package, everything is working fine except the fact that I'm adding some basic custom response headers such as JSON content type and nothing is being added at the final HTTP response headers.

In my particular case, I'm not using the `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer` because I'm building a serverless framework template.

- That is my Lambda function implementation:
  https://github.com/RichardSilveira/UserServerlessMicroservice/blob/master/src/userService/Functions/GetUserByIdFunction.cs

```cs
    public class GetUserByIdFunction : FunctionBase
    {
        private IUserRepository _userRepository;

        protected override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            var connString = Configuration["UserServiceDbContextConnectionString"];

            // serviceCollection.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connString));
            serviceCollection.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(connString));//temporarily

            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        }

        protected override void Configure(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _userRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IUserRepository>();
        }

        // Invoked by AWS Lambda at runtime
        public GetUserByIdFunction()
        {
        }

        public GetUserByIdFunction(
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            // Constructor used by tests
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }


        public async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> Handle(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            LogFunctionMetadata(request, context);

            if (!RunningAsLocal) ConfigureDependencies();

            var userId = Guid.Parse(request.PathParameters["userid"]);

            var user = await _userRepository.GetByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null) return NotFound();

            return Ok(user);
        }
    }
```

- My Function Base Implementation
  https://github.com/RichardSilveira/UserServerlessMicroservice/blob/master/src/userService/Functions/FunctionBase.cs

```cs
    public abstract class FunctionBase
    {
        protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
        protected bool RunningAsLocal = false;

        public FunctionBase() => Configuration = ConfigurationService.Instance.Configuration;

        public FunctionBase(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            RunningAsLocal = true;
        }

        protected void ConfigureDependencies()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            Configure(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
        }

        protected abstract void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection);
        protected abstract void Configure(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);

        protected void LogFunctionMetadata(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            LambdaLogger.Log($"CONTEXT {Serialize(context.GetMainProperties())}");
            LambdaLogger.Log($"EVENT: {Serialize(request.GetMainProperties())}");
        }

        protected APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse Ok() =>
            new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse()
            {
                StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Content-Type", "application/json"}
                }
            };

        protected APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse NotFound() =>
            new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse()
            {
                StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Content-Type", "application/json"}
                }
            };
    }
```

The only problem is that any header added to `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse` class is not being added to the final HTTP response as expected.

Note: I've already tried use the `SetHeaderValues` of it such as:

```cs
      protected APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse Ok(object body)
        { 
            var response = new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse()
            {
                StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = Serialize(body)
            };
            
            response.SetHeaderValues("Content-Type", "application/json", false);
            response.SetHeaderValues("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*", false);
            response.SetHeaderValues("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true", false);

            return response;
        }
```

### Reproduction Steps

`git clone https://github.com/RichardSilveira/UserServerlessMicroservice`
`cd UserServerlessMicroservice`
`cd src/userService`
`npm i -g serverless`

> Note: The serverless framework creates an abstraction layer upon Cloudformation, it means that a Stack will be deployed into the AWS Account, you can delete the stack easily - nothing will be charged at this stack that you'll upload.

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  profile: default
  runtime: dotnetcore3.1
  stage: dev
  region: sa-east-1
```

> You can inform a profile name from your local machine AWS credentials file in the `serverless.yml` file by adding a `profile: <name>` such as the in the example above. It's optional, if you do nothing the default profile will be used.

`build`
`sls deploy -v`

#### Logs

N/A

#### Environment

I believe that is better to show off all my project description file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <PackageId>aws-csharp</PackageId>
    <RootNamespace>UserService</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EventStore.Client" Version="20.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.dev.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.local.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added "application/json" to the media types of API Gateway?  Or is that the default?  I know I had to add like "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Creating the response as follows works fine

```cs
           new APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse()
            {
                StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = Serialize(body),
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"Content-Type", "application/json"},
                    {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"},
                    {"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"}
                }
            };
```

Instead of assigning another dictionary to the Headers property